# My Javascript output is reversed and I can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, binary

```js
    function addBinary(a, b) {
      var num = a + b;
      var str = "";

      function tryToAdd(x) {
        if (str.charAt(x) == 0 || !str || str.charAt(x) == null) {
          if (x == str.length) {
            str += "1";
          } else {
            str = str.substr(0, x) + "1" + str.substr(1 + x);
          }
        } else {
          str = str.substr(0, x) + "0" + str.substr(1 + x);
          tryToAdd(x + 1);
        }
      }
      for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        tryToAdd(0);
      }

      function reverse(s) {
          return s.split("").reverse().join("");
        } // reverse my string because I don't know why it's reversed in the first place lol
      var newStr = reverse(str);
      return newStr;
    }

    console.log(addBinary(1, 5));
```

This was made for some codewarrior thing.

I try to translate two added numbers into binary (didn't know about num.ToString(2) when I began) which I successfully did... backwards.

I found some help here on stack to reverse the output, but of course that didn't feel very satisfactory. I also took help from stack with the replacement of string values and tried to modify them, but things quickly went south when they were touched.

If I were to add a = 2 and b = 2, which is 4 and 100 in binary, the output would be (without my reverse function) 001. I just can't understand why zeroes would ever be put in the front by the lines. I suspect it's something with the recursive function.

Thankful for any help!

Edit: Sorry for rejecting the edit! I have no idea as to how I did that, it was not intentional at all.

Comment: Most likely caused by your substring function have a look

Comment: I think by "inception" you mean "recursive".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript string indices go from left to right. For example, `"abcd".charAt(1)` is `'b'`.

In your `tryToAdd` function, you use `x` as the index of the digit in your binary string to replace. If you change your definition to invert that index by subtracting it from the string length, then it will work without reversing:

```js
function addBinary(a,b){
    var num = a+b;
    var str = "";

    function tryToAdd(y){
        var x = str.length - y - 1; // correct for left-to-right strings
        if (str.charAt(x) == 0 || str.charAt(x) == null) {
            str = str.substr(0, x) + "1" + str.substr(1 + x);
        }
        else {
            str = str.substr(0, x) + "0" + str.substr(1 + x);
            tryToAdd(y+1); // recur on y, not x
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        tryToAdd(0);
    } 
    return str;
}

console.log(addBinary(1,5))
```

Note that I also got rid of the `x == str.length` condition, since it didn't seem to be doing anything useful.

---

I think you're just doing this for learning purposes, but I still wanted to make sure you knew that you can convert numbers to binary strings in JavaScript like this: `num.toString(2)`

Comment: Doesn't work for 6 + 10... should = 10000, but gives 1000010

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette - Works fine for me (https://jsfiddle.net/DaoWen/rypnnbo0/). The only string that doesn't come out right is `0`, but the original has that problem too.

Comment: At second look... Sorry about that, your script works fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is another way** to do the same as @DaoWen more concise answer.
I leave it here since it took time to edit and it is working.
Can be instructive for one some day.

**Anyway**, the proper way to convert a number into binary string is:`num.toString(2)`, as @DaoWen also mentionned.

I inserted a lot of console.log() for one to see each iteration.
I used jQuery just to get some number fields to use...
Could also have used getElementById...
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/oxnhp03L/

```
<!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>

    <style>


    </style>

    a: <input type="number" id="a"><br>
    b: <input type="number" id="b"><br>
    <br>
    <input type="button" id="add" value="Add a and b"><br>
    <br>
    result: <input type="text" id="response"><br>

<script>

$("#add").click(function(){
    addBinary($("#a").val(),$("#b").val())
});


function addBinary(a,b){
    console.log("a:"+a+" b:"+b);
    var num = parseInt(a)+parseInt(b);
    console.log("num: "+num);
    var str = "0";

    function tryToAdd(x){
        console.log("tryToAdd() iteration x: "+x+" - Since zero based, the number is: "+parseInt(x+1));
        if (str.charAt(str.length-1) == "0"){                   // IF last digit = 0 --> Change it for a 1
        console.log("Last char is zero.");
                str = str.substr(0, str.length-1) + "1";
        }
        else{                                                   // IF last digit = 1
            LastZero=str.lastIndexOf("0");                      // Check for a 0 somewhere else in the string and retreive position
            console.log("Last zero position: "+LastZero);
            if(LastZero==-1){                                   // If none, place a 1 and turn all digits to 0
                newStr="1";
                console.log("newStrA1: "+newStr);
                for(j=0;j<str.length;j++){
                    newStr+="0";
                    console.log("newStrA2: "+newStr);
                }
                console.log("newStrA3: "+newStr);

            }else{                                              // If a 0 somewhere, find the last.                     
                newStr=str.substr(0,LastZero);                  // keep the first part of the string
                console.log("newStrB1: "+newStr);

                newStr+="1"                                     // Turn this 0 into a 1 
                console.log("newStrB2: "+newStr);

                for(j=1;j<str.length-LastZero;j++){             // And add the remaining digits as 0
                    console.log("Iteration j="+j+", Adding remaining digits as zero.");
                    newStr+="0";
                    console.log("newStrB3: "+newStr);
                }
            }
            str=newStr;
        }
        console.log("------------------------------------------------------------- RESULT: "+str);
        console.log("");
    }


    for (i = 0; i <= num-1; i++){   // Removes 1 to your number, since tryToAdd() iterations are zero based.
        tryToAdd(i);                // Loops! 
    }

    $("#response").val(str);        // Returns the result in an input text.
}
</script>
```